# Display tag content that does not exist on the source page but exists in inspect element using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm going to display the contents inside `span` with the class `detail-price` in this page:

https://hamrahtel.com/detail/4598

To do this, I wrote the code as follows with `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser`:

```
function myfunc($url){

$html = @file_get_html($url);


    if ($html !=''){
            foreach($html->find("span.detail-price") as $e) { 
                
                $var = $e->plaintext ;
                    echo $var;
                    echo "<br>";

            }


    }
    else {
    echo "nothing found!";
};

}

myfunc("https://hamrahtel.com/detail/4639");
```

Unfortunately no value is displayed, while if we use inspect element you can see the `span` but in page source, This span does not exist!
Can you suggest a way for me to display the contents of this span?

Comment: Most likely the extra content is loaded by Javascript, possibly as a result of an AJAX call, which of course only executes in a browser where Javascript can run. So a simple file_get command can only download the initial content returned by the server, it can't execute the Javascript to get any more. You would need a headless browser type of solution

Comment: @ADyson Do you have any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: Not from personal experience but I would be surprised if a bit of sensible searching doesn't return something useful.